# PHP Array Sort List Returned From FTP Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have files returned in array from my ftp server:

```
Array
(
    [0] => FOLDER./Images.Vacation.2018
    [1] => ./Images.Vacation.2018/Racoon001.jpg
    [2] => ./Images.Vacation.2018/Racoon002.txt
    [3] => ./Images.Vacation.2018/the.racoon.swimming.mp4
    [4] => ./Images.Vacation.2018/the.racoon.swimming.slv
    [5] => FOLDER./WestImages
    [6] => ./WestImages/Ramco.txt
    [7] => ./WestImages/Ramco.jpg
    [8] => FOLDER./WestImages/Subimages
    [9] => ./WestImages/Subimages/Image001.jpg
    [10] => ./WestImages/Subimages/Image002.jpg
    [11] => ./WestImages/West.Ramco.Swimming.mp4
)
```

As you can see SubImages is returned before WestImages and this is wrong...so i can't show correct files in my folder using  and

tags...i need array to return this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => FOLDER./Images.Vacation.2018
    [1] => ./Images.Vacation.2018/Racoon001.jpg
    [2] => ./Images.Vacation.2018/Racoon002.txt
    [3] => ./Images.Vacation.2018/the.racoon.swimming.mp4
    [4] => ./Images.Vacation.2018/the.racoon.swimming.slv
    [5] => FOLDER./WestImages
    [6] => ./WestImages/Ramco.txt
    [7] => ./WestImages/Ramco.jpg
    [8] => ./WestImages/West.Ramco.Swimming.mp4
    [9] => FOLDER./WestImages/Subimages
    [10] => ./WestImages/Subimages/Image001.jpg
    [11] => ./WestImages/Subimages/Image002.jpg
)
```

This is my ftp code that reads files from server:

```
/* contents - ftp function */
    function ftp_list_files_recursive($ftp_stream, $path){
        $lines = ftp_rawlist($ftp_stream, $path);

        $result = array();

        foreach ($lines as $line){
            $tokens = explode(" ", $line);
            $name = $tokens[count($tokens) - 1];
            $type = $tokens[0][0];
            $filepath = $path . "/" . $name;

            if ($type == 'd'){
                $result[] = 'FOLDER'.$filepath;
                $result = array_merge($result, ftp_list_files_recursive($ftp_stream, $filepath));
            } elseif ($type == '-'){
                $result[] = $filepath;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /* contents - ftp */
    $contents = ftp_list_files_recursive($conn_id, ".");

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($contents);
    echo '</pre>';
```

I was trying using `sort($contents)`; but it return me wrong sorting...how to rewrite function to return correct sorting like given in above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not a pretty solution but you can use preg_grep to get the foldernames then loop them and grep the files.

```
$folders = preg_grep("/^FOLDER.*/", $arr);

foreach($folders as $folder){
    $result[] = $folder;
    $result = array_merge($result, preg_grep("/^\." . str_replace(["FOLDER.", "/"], ["","\/"], $folder) . "\/[A-Za-z0-9\.]+$/", $arr));
}

var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/BthA0

Comment: This is nice solution but i see that i have many folders with personal images that have this format: FOLDER./Images.Vacation.2018[cuba] and some of filenames contains _ and space in filename (for example: Racoon_001.jpg and Racoon 002.jpg so above code exclude these filenames...could you please add thease exceptions for folder and filenames to work? Thanks

Comment: This is the part with the file name `[A-Za-z0-9\.]` add the characters you need there. Just don't add `/` as that is a folder separator.

Comment: Thanks...i added '[A-Za-z0-9-_\.]' and is working but i have '[]' in folder name and then is not show..could you just add '[]' to preg because i don't know where to add..thanks

Comment: Yes you can add them, but you need to add them escaped. `[A-Za-z0-9-_\.\[\]]` since `[]` is part of regex patterns you need to add `\\` before them to make them literal.

Comment: I added '[A-Za-z0-9-_\.\[\]]' to the regex but it does not work..when folder name have [2008] it shows folder line but not files in folder so if you could check with example adding [] to regex to show files in folder that have [] in folder name...try for example...FOLDER./Images.Vacation.[2018] and files inside /Racoon001.jpg it will not show Racoon001.jpg inside this folder only folder name...could you please add regex code so that i can finish this part? Thanks for helping me out

Comment: I read and try before post but it won't work when added \[\] this is how now it looks: "\/[A-Za-z0-9-_\.\\[\\]]+$/"

Comment: Please see this example: https://3v4l.org/W3722 line 5 and 8 is show (correct) but it does not show files inside folder (need to show line 6 and 7)...so i think that \\[\\] needs to be in other location in regex?